# RXJS: Property animationFrame doesn't exsist on typeof Scheduler

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, scheduler, requestanimationframe

Trying to play around with RXJS and Scheduler.  In the end, I want to have a request animation frame on a scroll event.

Problem:
I'm getting a type error of: Property animationFrame doesn't exsist on typeof Scheduler

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/repeat';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import { Scheduler } from 'rxjs/Scheduler';

Observable
          .of(0, Scheduler.animationFrame) // error here
          .repeat()
          .takeUntil(Observable.timer(1000))
          .subscribe(() => console.log(x++));
```

[image]

### **Question:**

How do I get animationFrame to be recognized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since rxjs@6.0.0 `animationFrame` got renamed to `animationFrameScheduler` and has to be imported from `rxjs`.

```
import { animationFrameScheduler } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `AnimationFrameScheduler` you need to import it. `Scheduler` is a general scheduler class. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/scheduler/animationFrame.ts

```
import { animationFrame } from 'rxjs/scheduler/animationFrame';
```

Then use it like this:

```
Observable.of(0, animationFrame)
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be bit confusing but top level exported `Scheduler` and `rxjs/Scheduler` is different - prior is object contains instance of schedulers to be used, latter is Class to instantiate those. So to get animFrame scheduler instance,

```
import { animationFrame } from 'rxjs/scheduler/animationFrame';
```

I've edited answer per comment suggestion, as suggested it is better to import individual directly instead of import something from top level. once top-level import occurs it'll make all operator patching etcs, loading whole library at once so need to be used with caution. (or better not in general).

Comment: Never import from `rxjs` or `rxjs/Rx`.